# Matches in a string in Java

Tags: java, string, variables, match

I have this code:

```
String string = "40' & 40' HC";
if(string.matches("&"))
   System.out.println("Found");
```

But the condition won't be true. why?
Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: its not clear - which condition won't be true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: should have used `string.contains("&")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.matches(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) is for a regular expression. I suggest you add an `else` (and [`{}`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accolade)) and I believe you wanted [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and something like

```
if (string.contains("&")) {
    System.out.println("Found");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "40' & 40' HC";
if(string.contains("&"))
 System.out.println("Found");
```

replace .matches with .contains, i believe you are trying to check for a character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

It's misnamed `.matches()` method in JAVA. It tries and matches ALL the input.

`String.matches` returns whether the whole string matches the regex, not just any substring.

Use `Pattern`

```
String string = "40' & 40' HC";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
if (m.find())
  System.out.println("Found");
```